# How to determine crown ether cavity size?

Tags: solvents, extraction

I want to determine the cavity radius/ dia of crown ether. Which technique should I follow?

Comment: Knowing the crystal structure and van der Waals radii of the atoms forming the cavity it's a matter of finding distance between two points in 3D space. Many molecular editors and crystal structure software such as Avogadro or Mercury can do that via a couple of mouse clicks.